# Calling the JSON correctly

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I have a JSON array fetched from the service to the controller. I'm able to display the JSON array in the console. But when a specific item from the JSON, is called it display's `undefined`. So how do I call it correctly so that I can use it in my view.

Controller:

```
$scope.onViewLoaded = function() {
  callingService.getdata($scope.datafetched);
}

$scope.datafetched = function(response) {
  debugger;
  if (response) {
    $rootScope.mainData = response;
    $scope.localizeddataTypes = getLocalizedCollection($scope.mainData);
  }
}

$scope.editFunction = function(key) {
  console.log($scope.mainData);
  debugger;
  console.log($scope.mainData.keyValue);
}
```

Here `console.log($scope.mainData);` display's the JSON array but `console.log($scope.mainData.keyValue);` is displayed as undefined. And my JSON looks like

```
{ 
   keyValue: "1234DEF56", 
   animals: {
      name:"dog",
      color:"brown"
   },
   birds:{
      name:"canary",
      color:"yellow"
   }
}
```

So, how do I overcome this problem and why do I get it as `Undefined`.

Comment: I don't see any array in your JSON data. Anyway, I suspect @Praveen is right

Answer (score 3):

Just a curiosity stuff. I feel that the content in that variable is stored in string format and not JSON or JavaScript Object. Try this, and see if that works?

```
$scope.mainData = JSON.parse($scope.mainData);
console.log($scope.mainData.keyValue);
```